# exited segmentation fault al crear elementos dinámicos en el constructor

Tags: c++

```
class Staff{
public:
  Staff();
  Staff * list;
};

int main(){
  Staff * personnel = new Staff();

  return 0;
}

Staff::Staff(){
  int size = 1;
  list = new Staff[size];
}
```

El error está cuando en el constructor reservo el espacio para la lista del staff, y me salta un `exited segmentation fault`. Lo hago de esa forma para después poder agregar otras clases hijas a esa lista. ¿De qué forma debería declarar esa lista?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ¿De qué forma debería declarar esa lista?

Una cosa es una clase y otra una lista de objetos. De la misma manera, tu deberías tener dos clases en vez de solo una: La que representa al objeto en sí mismo y otra para gestionar la lista:

```
class Staff
{
};

class List{
    Staff* list = nullptr;
};
```

Es muy importante proporcionar responsabilidades simples a cada elemento. Si una clase tiene que gestionar datos, y también una lista, y también interactuar con el sistema de archivos, y también ... al final se acaba convirtiendo en un monstruo titánico que no vas a ser capaz de domar.

Es más facil y cómodo gestionar por un lado toda la información sobre el personal (clase `Staff`)  y, por otro, gestionar una posible lista de objetos.

```
class List
{
public:

    void Add(Staff* item);
    void Delete(Staff* item);
    // ...
};
```

> Lo hago de esa forma para después poder agregar otras clases hijas a esa lista

Mientras uses punteros no deberías tener problemas en este aspecto. Si has estudiado como funciona el polimorfismo sabrás que un puntero de la clase base es capaz de manejar punteros de clases derivadas:

```
class Staff
{
  public:
    virtual void Print() const
    { return "Staff"; }
};

class B : public Staff
{
  public:
    void Print() const override
    { return "B"; }
};

Staff * ptr1 = new Staff();
Staff * ptr2 = new B();

ptr1->Print();
std::cout << '\n';
ptr2->Print();
```

Ahora bien, en lo que falla tu diseño es en que estás haciendo uso de un puntero simple. Si solo quieres almacenar un objeto no tendrás problema, como has podido comprobar en el ejemplo que se encuentra sobre estas líneas.

Peeeeero al intentar apuntar a una colección de objetos vas a ver que te resulta imposible almacenar objetos de diferente tipo.

¿Y eso?

Para entender el problema hay que ver cómo se gestiona la memoria. Cuando tu llamas a `new[]` el Sistema Operativo te proporciona una región de memoria donde entran X objetos de tipo Y:

```
Staff * lista = new Staff[5]; // 5 objetos de tipo Staff
```

Es decir:

```
| Staff0 | Staff1 | Staff2 | Staff3 | Staff4 |
|--------------------------------------------|
^ posición de memoria del inicio del bloque reservado
```

Fíjate que todos los elementos tienen exactamente el mismo tamaño.

Por otro lado tenemos que las clases derivadas pueden (y suelen) tener más variables miembro, lo que hace que los objetos de estas clases derivadas ocupen más en memoria:

```
| Tamaño del objeto ----> 
| Staff |
| B            |
| C         |
```

Como puedes comprobar, en un hueco de tamaño X no puedes meter un objeto de tamaño Y si Y>X

Para solucionar este y otros problemas que no expongo para no alargarme en exceso hay que usar un puntero doble:

```
Staff ** list;
```

De esta forma lo que hacemos es reservar memoria para almacenar X punteros a objetos de tipo `Staff`:

```
list = new Staff*[5]; // espacio para 5 punteros de tipo Staff
```

Da la casualidad que los punteros son variables que ocupan todos exactamente lo mismo independientemente de su tipo en concreto:

```
std::cout << sizeof(Staff*) << '\n'
          << sizeof(B*) << '\n'
          << sizeof(int****) << '\n'
          << sizeof(double**) << '\n';
```

Así pues, al usar un puntero doble lo que consigues es tener espacio para almacenar punteros... sin importar su tipo concreto puesto que ocupan todos lo mismo. El único requisito es que los punteros deben ser compatibles (herencia de clases):

```
list -> | Item0   | Item1   | Item2   | Item3   | Item4   |
        | Staff*  | B*      | Staff*  | B*      | B*      |
```

Ahora, para rellenar la lista, simplemente tienes que crear objetos del tipo que tu quieras:

```
Staff ** list = new Staff*[2];
list[0] = new Staff;
list[1] = new B;

for( int i=0; i<2; i++ )
{
  list[i]->Print();
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema es muy sencillo: la instrucción

```
Staff *personnel = new Staff( );
```

provoca un llamada recursiva e infinita al propio constructor, con lo cual tu sistema se queda sin memoria. Observa que, dentro del propio constructor, haces

```
list = new Staff[size];
```

El `operator new` en *array* llama al constructor por defecto, con lo que entras al constructor. Que vuelve a llamar a `new`. Con lo que vuelves a entrar en el constructor, que vuelve a llamar a `new` ... Así empieza la recursividad, y nunca termina.

Una posible solución es no reservar memoria en el constructor:

```
Staff::Staff( ) {
  list = nullptr;
}
```

Con lo cual ya no tendrias ese problema ... ha consta de comprobar, cada vez que lo necesites, que la variable-miembro `personnel` ha sido inicializada.

Lo cual puedes hacer muy facilmente, añadiendo un *getter* para obtener el valor de tu variable:

```
Staff *Staff::list( ) {
  if( !list ) { list = new Staff[1000]; }

  return list;
}
```

Comment: y de requerir reservar memoria para indicar el tamaño que tendra la lista, en donde se lo indicaría?

Comment: Te va a dar igual. Aunque le indiques el tamaño, seguirías llamando al constructor por defecto en cada uno de los elementos de la lista. La única solución es utilizar 2 constructores, o un contador total de elementos, o algo que *corte* la recursividad.

Comment: @NicolasFredsny Una mejor solución es usar un `getter( )` para obtener el valor del puntero, y comprobar ahí si `== nullptr`, con lo cual podrias reservar lo que necesites.

Comment: @NicolasFredsny He editado con un ejemplo de como podria ser un *getter*.